# Free specific type of memory allocation in C

Tags: c, malloc, free

I've found an interesting way to allocate matrices in C which allows the use of `[i][j]` without initializing as `double matrix_a[nrows][ncols]`. The allocation is

```
double (*matrix_a)[ncols] = (double (*)[ncols])malloc(sizeof(double) * (nrows) * (ncols));
```

But I can't find how to properly free this type of allocation. Would it be as simple as `free(matrix_a)`?

Comment: What is unique in this allocation? Typical allocation+cast.

Comment: It's unique only in the sense that I've never seen it before. I ran out of memory pretty quick allocating with `double matrix_a[nrows][ncols]` and found this style looking for more efficient methods.

Comment: You just allocated memory on the heap. `double a[m][n]` allocates on the stack, and stack is more limited than heap (typically). There is nothing special here.

Comment: [do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: OT: The cast isn't needed in C, nor is it recommended in any way. It's just useless.

Comment: OT: Also it's more robust to instead of `sizeof(double) * (nrows) * (ncols)`  use `nrows * sizeof *matrix_a`.

Comment: @alk it had a C++ tag some time ago. In C++ you do cast the result of malloc.

Comment: Better yet, use `malloc( sizeof(double[nrows][ncols]) )`. Self-documenting code is good code.

Comment: Also this code probably won't work well in C++, since C++ doesn't have VLA:s yet. You'd have to use compile-time constants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is correct.  You may only pass to `free` what was returned from `malloc` and family.  So since you did one `malloc`, you do one `free`.

Also, [there is no need to cast the return value of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc):

```
double (*matrix_a)[ncols] = malloc(sizeof(double) * (nrows) * (ncols));
```

Comment: If I remove the cast, I get `error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘double (*)[ncols]’ [-fpermissive]`

Comment: @mjswartz That's because you're compiling with a C++ compiler, not a C compiler.  C++ does require the cast.